# Searching in a webview

Tags: android, webview

when data is entered in the search bar in the picture, I want to search the WebView site. How can I do that?
What I need is to take the text from the search box and transfer it to a variable. How can I do that?

Data entered for example: weather

Changing WebView URL: www.wordpress-examplesite.com/?s=weather

I'm using WordPress and I'm projecting it to WebView.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to search in your entire site? Or, searching that text on currently loaded page?

Comment: @anirban I want to search the entire site. For example, the user will enter a text and the text will be searched on my site.

Comment: Think of it as this: you entered a site and searched for text, and you came up with results.The results are displayed in WebView.

Comment: What I need is to take the text from the search box and transfer it to a variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have implemented SearchView. Please use this to search your entire site-

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
String url = "http://wordpress-example-site/?s=";

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){ 
@Override 
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
webView.loadUrl(url+query);
return false;
 } 
 @Override 
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { 
 return false;
  } 
  });
```

Comment: If it solves your problem, then please upvote or accept this answer.

Comment: @anirban What I'm looking for is exactly what you did. But I couldn't integrate it. I'm very new at this, could you write a little more clearly? I get mistakes.

Comment: Have you implemented SearchView & WebView in your activity class? Could you please share your activity class what you have implemented so far?

Comment: @AnirbanRoy Do yo have skype? please contact me. Skype: arthurfrankasabiyovic

Comment: I would suggest you to get some knowledge here https://www.journaldev.com/12478/android-searchview-example-tutorial